# R: using clusterExport() to load libraries into cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to find ways to speed up loading my objects into a cluster with R's `parallel` package:

So far I've been using this method of loading my objects into the cluster:

```
# Generate cluster
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_threads)

# Load constants into each node's environment
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, expr = {
  library(glmGamPoi)
  NULL
})
parallel::clusterExport(cl, list('neg_binomial_fit', # Functions
                                 'cell_attr', 'bin_size'), env = environment()) # Objects
```

However, I've noticed that I can also somehow export libraries loaded in my master process into the cluster like so(this is part of my downstream code), and it seems to load the package much faster(I assume because it's just copying the library from the master process):

```
# Load constants into each node's environment
parallel::clusterExport(cl, list('Matrix', # Packages
                                 'corcounts_and_calcresvar', # Functions
                                 'cell_attr', 'min_var', 'clip_range', 'bin_size'), env = environment()) # Objects
```

Here I'm not using `clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(package_name) })` to load the `Matrix` package into each node(it's needed so the cluster knows how to subset the sparse matrix), rather I think I'm just exporting the loaded package using `clusterExport` . When I try to do this with the initial code with `glmGamPoi` , it for some reason doesn't work and instead returns `Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'glmGamPoi' not found`.

Right now I'm thinking either `Matrix` is a unique case or `glmGamPoi` is somehow hidden in my global environment so I cannot send it without accessing it in some special way. I've tried loading the library right before exporting it but that didn't work either so I'm just stumped as to what to do. I've also tried other random packages like `BiocManager` and these didn't work either.

Comment: Nevermind I think I'm loading the whole package regardless when doing `clusterExport('Matrix')` because it's actually just a function from the package: `Matrix::Matrix()`. When I load the function I need from `glmGamPoi`, it takes the same amount of time when just loading the library the typical way. I think I solved it, but if anyone finds a way to export loaded libraries like how I'm thinking I'd be really interested in how that would work

Comment: You can't load packages with `clusterExport` like that, The second parameter to that function is a list of variables that you want to export to the worker threads, not packages.

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your follow-up comment, exporting `"Matrix"`, will export the `Matrix::Matrix` object. This will trigger the **Matrix** package to be *loaded*, but not *attached*.  So, effectively, you're doing an implicit:

```r
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, loadedNamespace("Matrix"))
```

You can see this if you do the following in a fresh R session:

```r
> cl <- parallel::makeCluster(1L)
> parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, "Matrix" %in% loadedNamespaces())
[[1]]
[1] FALSE   ## 'Matrix' is not loaded on the parallel worker
```

Then continue with:

```r
library(Matrix)
> parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, "Matrix" %in% loadedNamespaces())
[[1]]
[1] FALSE   ## still not loaded ("obviously")

> parallel::clusterExport(cl, "Matrix")
> parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, "Matrix" %in% loadedNamespaces())
[[1]]
[1] TRUE    ## 'Matrix' was loaded because of the export of Matrix::Matrix
```

Note that **Matrix** is only *loaded*, but not *attached*;

```r
> parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, "package::Matrix" %in% search())
[[1]]
[1] FALSE
```

This is fine; all **Matrix**-specific operators work just fine, including subsetting.

So, you could replace your:

```r
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, library("Matrix"))
```

and

```r
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, loadedNamespace("Matrix"))
```

to be explicit about which packages you rely on in the parallel workers, while making it clear that they do not need to be *attached*.